# Local variable in loop

Tags: ruby, erb

I have the following code in an ERB template:

```
<% ['foo', 'bar'].each do |var| %>
  <%= previous %>
  <% previous = "#{var}" %>
<% end %>
```

I would expect it to output `foo`, but it outputs nothing, `previous` is always `nil`. `previous` is not defined outside the loop, the first assignment happens after the end of the first loop.

This is how I'm rendering the template:

```
f.write ERB.new(File.read(node)).result(namespace.instance_eval { binding })
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<% previous = "" %>
<% ['foo', 'bar'].each do |var| %>
  <%= previous %>
  <% previous = var %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You had a scoping issue and the var thing you did was a syntax bug